# Django ignore method for ALLOWED_HOSTS and django-cors-headers

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

In my app, I defined ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, but I have some methods which I want to be ignored from ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, in other words I want to access those methods from from everywhere. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "from everywhere"? Like, would you like these addresses to have no CORS headers, or different CORS headers?

Comment: Also why would you need to ignore ALLOWED_HOSTS? it doesn't prevent your methods to be called from everywhere.

Comment: I want to access those methods from other sites, apps, etc. with no CORS and different CORS. I want that ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS not to run for those methods.

Comment: If I want to call a url directly from browser, I need to ignore ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: there are good reasons why you dont want to do that. If you  have useful python fucntions and want them be accasable from anywhere, build APIs or make another django project...

Comment: I don't think you need to ignore ALLOWED_HOSTS, doesn't the browser provide a valid Host header? Anyway, have you seen the[`check_request_enabled` signal](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers#signals)? Sounds like exactly what you ask for

Comment: Didn't saw ```cors_allow_api_to_everyone```, that is ok. And you are right with ALLOWED_HOSTS I don't know where was my head, post the answer so I can accept it. Thank you.